# Load a simple text file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, assets, streamreader

Got a brand new project using Google's new Android Studio IDE.

I'm trying to load a simple text file using an `InputStreamReader`. I'm getting a file not found exception. Now there isn't any assets/ folder. I tried to create one and add my file at many different spots (at the root of the project, at the root of the .java file, etc...) I've tried to move the file around but still get the file not found.

Now that never was a problem using Eclipse as there is an assets folder created by any template.

Does anyone know where should the assets go to or how to load them?

Here is the code used, it fails at .open():

```
InputStream iS = resources.getAssets().open("bla.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iS));
```

I also tried this code in Eclipse, it works and the file contents get loaded. So there's probably a step needed in Android Studio.

Comment: Create what? the streamReader?

Comment: no, the assets folder.

Comment: Right click on the project and -> New-> directory, the folder appears just fine, then I drag the text file into it.

Comment: Please show the code where you load the file.

Comment: sure, look at the 'edit'

Comment: @Simon Please clarify your second sentence in your first comment

Comment: @cja.  Sure.  Studio has plenty of bugs and can be difficult to work with.  it is not yet released and is not certified for building Android apps.  The post suggests that the OP is not very experienced so my recommendation would be to stick with tried and tested released software.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

1. Step 1:
               Open in Name_Project-Name_Project.iml file.
2. See the line :
               option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/assets"
3. Step 2:
               Create a sub-folder "assets" in main folder.
4. Step 3:
               Put file in this folder.
5. Step 4:
               Load it. Done.

Comment: Correct answer. The path entry in the .iml file is key. Thank you.

Comment: Outstanding...been searching for this for over an hour, and all the Eclipse-based ideas failed. THANK YOU FIT226557! :)

Comment: This was frustrating the crap out of me! Thank you! +1

Comment: There is no line like step 2 says in my .iml file ?

Comment: Don't open the main project .iml file, but instead open the main module's .iml file. E.g. If your project is "MyProject" and what you actually run is "app", then open the "MyProject/app/app.iml" file. Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't a project just one module?

Comment: so what's the path in the code to access the files then?

Comment: @FIT226557 I did as said in the answer, but still the file is not found when I run the activity. File doesn't exist error comes. Any more suggestions for that? 
on Ubuntu 12.04-Android Studio-64bit

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer didn't work for me exactly.
This works:

Go to Project view and then go to `app/src/main` and create new directory `assets`

to load the file:

```
   InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("bla.txt");
```

or:

```
   InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("bla.txt");
```

and then convert it to string at any way you want, [examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

[detailed video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CHDASXojNQ) of how to do it (not mine)

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for you.It will fetch all data from file.

```
public class Quiz extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    try {
        PlayWithRawFiles();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Problems: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}// onCreate

public void PlayWithRawFiles() throws IOException {
    String str="";
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ashraf);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    if (is!=null) {
        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buf.append(str + "\n" );
        }
    }
    is.close();
   TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv.setText(buf.toString());


}//
        }
```

Comment: u have to create raw folder inside res directory and add your file there

Answer (score 0):

//Compiled all the codes available in the internet, and this works perfectly fine for reading data from a textfile
//Compiled By: JimHanarose

```
 ArrayList<String> data_base = new ArrayList<String>();
    String text = "";
    try {
        InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("g.txt"); //save this .txt under src/main/assets/g.txt
        int size = is.available();
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        byte [] buffer = new byte[size];
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        if (is!=null) {
            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                data_base.add(text.toString()); //create your own arraylist variable to hold each line being read from g.txt 
            }
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```