# Android Typeface createFromAsset

Tags: android, android-fonts, android-typeface

I Have a Custom View which draws text onto the `Canvas`.
I want to change the `font` to a font stored in the **assets** folder.

I am using `Android Studio` so I created a folder **src/main/assets** and placed my ttf files in there.

```
Paint txt = new Paint()
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "robotobold.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Problem is `Android Studio` doesn't recognize **getAssets()** inside my Custom View, however, it recognizes it inside my Activity. I have tried passing `Typeface` through from my `Activity` but when I do it it doesn't change the `font`.

Comment: One suggestion, if you want to apply custom font from assets better create a custom class that extends TextView inside which you can set the typeface and use it in xml layouts so that, at runtime you don't need to apply the typeface for all TextViews.

Comment: Found a library usage, this contains multiple view like textview, editext, button and many more http://stackoverflow.com/a/42001474/4446392

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use your `View`'s `getContext()` method to get the current `Context`, then use it to get the *assets*:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "robotobold.ttf");
```

Answer (score 34):

First of all, you have to keep your `assets` folder inside your `project` and not inside `src/main`.. And then, create a folder called `fonts` inside `assets`. then, put the specific font typeface `ttf files` inside it.You can use the font typeface in coding like:

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/filename.ttf");
textview.setTypeface(type);
```

Comment: thanks I was trying "/fonts/ ..." and android.os just could not grab the font. Removing dash, made the android system able to recognize the font file.

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by your "inside your project"?
The app can't find the fonts, I have them in "/src/main/assets/font" too.

Answer (score 5):

created a folder src/main/assets and placed font files in there.

in Activity

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "Mukta-Regular.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

in Fragment

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "Mukta-Regular.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to place your assets folder **inside "Project" folder** and **not in the "src" folder**. You have placed your font in the ***"src/main/assets/robotobold.ttf"*** that's why it is not working. ***You need to place it like this "/assets/robotobold.ttf".***

Comment: I did that at first, but then cam across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821182/load-a-simple-text-file-in-android-studio

Comment: No, that is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reuse typefaces in my projects I create a class full of typeface methods, this way I dont have to create a new typeface every time.

I call the class `FontClass` and in the class there is a method for each typeface I need to use e.g:

```
public static Typeface getOpenSansRegular(Context c){
    return Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "OpenSans-Light.ttf");
}
```

Then I can use them like so:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
text.setTypeface(FontClass.getOpenSansRegular(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: How does that prevent creating a new typeface every time?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Typeface robo = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was adding the line

```
Typeface mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "abc.ttf");
```

before onCreate()