# Typeface causes for "Unfortunately (app name) hast stopped"

Tags: java, android, typeface, android-fonts

In `BaseGameActivity.java` I have the methods which creates easily typeface. But somehow the app stops unfortunately when it comes to create typeface. The code does not contain syntax error.

> BaseGameActivity.java

```
public class BaseGameActivity extends Activity {

    private Map<String,Typeface> typefaces = new HashMap<String,Typeface>();

    protected void addTypeface(String name) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), name+".tff");
        typefaces.put(name, typeface);
    }

    protected void setTypeface(TextView v, String typefaceName) {
        Typeface t = typefaces.get(typefaceName);
        if(t != null) {
            v.setTypeface(t);
        }
    }
}
```

> MainAcitivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

    private static final String FONTNAME = "airmole";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addTypeface(FONTNAME);
        setTypeface((TextView) findViewById(R.id.title), FONTNAME);
    }
}
```

The file `airmole.tff` is in the `assets` folder.

> logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
        at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:319)
        at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:293)
        at de.ucarweb.tools.BaseGameActivity.addTypeface(BaseGameActivity.java:23)
        at de.ucarweb.silverball.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
```

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: What does `logcat` say when it crashes?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049643/runtimeexception-native-typeface-cannot-be-made)

Comment: In the link, there are suggestions, but no one of them did work. Where is the is problem exactly.

Comment: Those were just two links that showed up right away with the same error. There were several more. Are you sure `getAssets()` is working? Try moving your `Typeface` code to the main activity instead of making the method calls just see if it behaves any differently.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you should do something like that :

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), name+".tff");
```

Comment: How is this different from what's in the question? It adds getContext() but the code  is in an Activity which is already a context. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Several cases was solved thanks to that solution.

You can check an example here : [an other case about getAssets()][1]

Or you can documentation there : [Documentation][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436703/android-typeface-createfromasset
  [2]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#getContext

Comment: The first link is about getAssets() not being available on View, the second is a link to api docs for Dialog. Neither applies here, the posted code is inside an _Activity_