# Android Font Selector GUI not available in Xml design

Tags: android

Am using android studio 3.3.
Am trying to design my activities in xml and i want to change the font family.
There used to be a fontFamily option where i can choose a custom font from android studio GUI.
Am missing it.
[image]

Comment: I'm running 3.3 and I have it. Maybe your install of Android Studio got borked? If nothing else, you might be able add it yourself in "view all attributes" or in text.

Comment: its neither in all attributes.

Comment: its necessary to change through XML?

Comment: i din't get waht you meant @TanveerMunir

Comment: I want to say you can use typeFace for text labels through programmatically

Comment: Yes i can.  But i want to use this GUI thing because it seems simple and straight foward. and i've always been using it

Comment: @makamuevans please have look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [URL](https://android.jlelse.eu/downloadable-fonts-android-283b0cc21934) how can you download the available fonts which provides `Android Studio`.

And here the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts).

Otherwise, you can set the typeFace programmatically [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436703/android-typeface-createfromasset)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone facing this, apparently after using android studio for a couple of days, the font option was automatically added to the GUI. I don't know how.
Probably those are things android studio downloads in the background for a while.